# Swift - Declare nested variable names using dot

Tags: swift, variables, nested, var, names

I'll keep it short. I'm trying to accomplish the following:

```
class Media {

var likes.count : Int? = 0  

}
```

Obviously the complier throws me an `error`:

```
Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'
```

Is there a way to work around this? I know that i can eventually do some kind of `String Replace` using `Mirror(reflecting:object)` but i'd like to keep it efficient. **Would love any help. Thanks.**

**UPDATE:**

I wasn't clear enough, sorry. The issue is that **the complier won't let me use `.` inside the variable declaration name.**

Comment: But, what would you want the `likes` to contain?
Can you give an example of a parallel feature in other language?

Comment: Hey @Etgar , Thank you for responding. I wasn't clear enough I guess. I'm referring the "likes.count" only as a name, literal name of the variable (not as a nested class or something). The issue is the the complier won't let me use a '.' inside my variable name..

Comment: This may be helpful; https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html

Comment: Now your issue is clear enough, thanks for clarifying it.
I'm pretty sure there isn't an efficient possibility of changing this basic rule of the compiler.
Just because I'm curious, why would you want to do something like this?

Comment: Thank you @rmp, I'll check it.

Comment: @LeoDabus I don't think he wants to return a tuple.

Comment: @Etgar I'm making a "total generic" network layer to deal with my endpoint ( It's an experiment) requests. Basically, I'm using the actual variable name to access the parsed JSON value, as a Key. (which is eventually a NSDictionary) using NSDictionary "value(forKeyPath: "a.b")" function. I was able to use it successfully with "non nested" properties, but when it's nested I'm trying to make it as generic as possible, using only the variable name. That's why the '.' is important.

Comment: @LeoDabus see comment above

Comment: @Etgar see two comments above

Comment: The `.` has a very specific meaning in Swift (as in many other languages). If you use it for property names then how can the compiler tell when you want to access a sub-element or simply a property with that specific name?

Comment: Maybe 'Properties' design pattern which is implemented in Swift 4 could help you to implement your thought: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html

Comment: @appzYourLife I'm do aware of the issue. One possible way to solve this would be calling variable with 'likes$count' for example. Than on runtime (after fetching the variable names, as String), replace '$' with '.'. I have no idea how much processor power it'll take (let's assume it'll replace string 10k times). Will it be noticeable performance wise?

Comment: @Etgar See suggestions above

Comment: @LeoDabus See suggestions two comments above

Comment: I wouldn't struggle with that... Sounds extremely inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

> The issue is that the complier won't let me use `.` inside the variable declaration name.

Exactly, a property name in Swift cannot contain the `.` character.

### A possible approach

Now, if you want to be able to write something like this

```
let media = Media()
media.likes.count = 1
```

then you need to define your class like shown below

```
class Media {
    class Likes {
        var count = 0
    }
    var likes = Likes()
}
```

or

```
class Likes {
    var count = 0
}

class Media {
    var likes = Likes()
}
```

### A few suggestions

**PLEASE** don't use implicitly unwrapped optionals like this one

```
var likes.count : Int! = 0
```

They are like a gun ready to fire and crash your entire app!

And finally the `class` keyword begins with a lowercase character: `class` not `Class`.

Comment: I was aware of the issue, Here is why i specifically  needed the '.' solution. I'm making a "total generic" network layer to deal with my endpoint ( It's an experiment) requests. Basically, I'm using the actual variable name to access the parsed JSON value, as a Key. (which is eventually a NSDictionary) using NSDictionary "value(forKeyPath: "a.b")" function. I was able to use it successfully with "non nested" properties, but when it's nested I'm trying to make it as generic as possible, using only the variable name. That's why the '.' is important

Comment: Edited^. I've just wrote quick example

Comment: You need to think harder about what AppzYourLife is telling you. In Swift 4, you will be able to parse the JSON _directly_ into a nested struct of just the sort he describes, with no work on your part.

Comment: Hey @matt. Always nice when you are commenting. Remember your great answers far as two years ago :). Unfortunately I'm planning to ship the product before iOS 11 launch (when xCode 9 will no longer be beta). So so far i'm "stuck" with Swift 3, or you know of a way releasing app with Swift 4?

Comment: I guess what I don't understand is why you need to represent a _key_ as a variable _name_. A key should be a variable _value_. It wouldn't matter what the name is as long as `"likes.count"` was its value. Now you have a key path and you're home free. But since there is no introspection in Swift (no real introspection) it makes no sense to do this with a _name_. (If I'm grasping the problem correctly, that is. No guarantee of that.)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a [Struct](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html). A `Struct` is basically the same as a class that is referenced by value. So you can have as many `Struct`s as you want with their own nested `variables` and `functions`, just like a class! And the best part is, you never have to use the `Struct` as a functional piece of code, just as something to namespace your variables in. I do this frequently with a `Constants` swift file.

```
struct Constants {

    struct MainMenu {
        static var height:CGFloat = 420
        static var width:CGFloat = 240
        static var backgroundColor:UIColor = .red
    }

    struct MainViewController {
        static var toolBarHeight:CGFloat = 49
        static var backgroundColor:UIColor = .blue
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
func getRemainingHeight() ->CGFloat {
    let viewHeight    = self.view.bounds.size.height
    let menuHeight    = Constants.MainMenu.height
    let toolBarHeight = Constants.MainViewController.toolBarHeight
    return viewHeight - (menuHeight + toolBarHeight)
}
```

Comment: Hey Brandon, thank you for answering. The main issue is that i need some how to fetch those 'Constants.MainViewController' as an actual string. Copying previous answer of mine

Comment: I'm making a "total generic" network layer to deal with my endpoint ( It's an experiment) requests. Basically, I'm using the actual variable name to access the parsed JSON value, as a Key. (which is eventually a NSDictionary) using NSDictionary "value(forKeyPath: "a.b")" function. I was able to use it successfully with "non nested" properties, but when it's nested I'm trying to make it as generic as possible, using only the variable name. That's why the '.' is important.

Comment: @RoiMulia Everything about that makes me hurt.

Comment: @Alexander Well, sometimes you just have to try :) Curiosity always wins

Comment: @RoiMulia You're coupling your network serialization to your code's data types. You're one innocent variable rename away from permanently breaking your communication layer

Comment: @Alexander Thanks for responding Alex. I'm do aware of that, I know and have built various of network layers before (not showing off at all), but i'm do aware of the risks and the so many disadvantages at this scenario. Again, i'm trying to experiment for the name of knowledge, nothing else. But thank you for giving heads-up, always appreciating!

Comment: @RoiMulia Have fun with it, but do be aware of the many limitations and hardships along the way. For one, `mirror` doesn't represent any superclass members, so inheritance will be completely unsupported by your scheme

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147412/discussion-between-roi-mulia-and-alexander).